# operand type mismatch for `out', 'in'

Tags: c, osdev, protected-mode

I have this function:

```
uint8_t getcmosflpd(void)
{
    uint8_t c;
    outb(0x70, 0x10);
    c = inb(0x70);
    return c;
}
```

When I compile it, I obtain this errors:

```
/tmp/ccMmuD7U.s:28: Error: operand type mismatch for `out'
/tmp/ccMmuD7U.s:39: Error: operand type mismatch for `in'
```

This are my outb and inb functions:

```
static inline void outb(uint16_t port, uint8_t val)
{
    asm volatile ("outb %0, %1" : : "a"(val), "Nd"(port));
}

static inline uint8_t inb(uint16_t port)
{
    uint8_t ret;
    asm volatile ("inb %1, %0"
                   : "=a"(ret)
                   : "Nd"(port));
    return ret;
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The compiler complains about `in` and `out` but the code ever mentions `inb` and `outb`. Are you sure those are the lines the compiler is complaining about ?

Comment: Mystery solved, I was compiling it with -masm=intel... :facepalm:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was compiling with `-masm=intel`. Always check your compiler flags!

Comment: Note that it's possible to write the asm such that it compiles whichever asm syntax you are using.  Check out [Multiple assembler dialects](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Multiple-assembler-dialects-in-asm-templates) in the docs.